# PHP doesn't execute on Mavericks OS

Tags: php, osx-mavericks

PHP won't work on my Mavericks (OS X 10.9.2).

Situation:
Brand new laptop, started apache server

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Went to localhost it says "It works"

Went to localhost/test.php, it displays the code and it doesn't execute as expected.

Uncommented php5_module line on httpd.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

from:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

saved file ':wq!'

Restarted apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

PHP still won't execute, it now DOWNLOADs the file.

How can I get it to execute PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following to your httpd.conf?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

Comment: That line wasn't there, I just added and restarted it. It still downloads the file...

Comment: @StephaniAlves have you restarted the server again after adding it?

Comment: @nl-x yes, I have. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, restarting the computer fixed everything. I guess just restarting the server doesn't work.

Comment: Restarting apache should work. My first thought is that apachectl might be dealing with a different copy of Apache than was running.